# How many S3 buckets should I have?

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm setting up a photo sharing service and each user will be able to upload images to their account. Is it a good idea to have one Amazon S3 bucker per user or is it acceptable to have every users pictures in one 'master' bucket? (or maybe one bucket with a folder per user?)

Answer (score 12):

One bucket will do the trick, think of buckets as 'projects'. There's also a limit of 100 buckets per AWS account, if I remember correctly.

Just have a decent directory structure and you'll be fine. One folder per user sounds good. Maybe something like this?

```
bucket_name
   user_images
     user_1             
     user_2
     user_n+1
   other_stuff
   more_stuff
```